# Custom theme folder

Tags: themes, directory, wp-config

Is anyone aware of an equivalent to `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL` for themes that I can define in `wp-config.php`, or am I stuck creating a mu-plugin and registering a new theme dir?

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83102/how-do-you-change-the-theme-location. This is the only way.

Comment: How do you define themes in config?

Comment: @Rarst: isn't that the point of my question? :-)

Comment: Misread the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default theme directory is registered like this in `wp-settings.php`

```
// Register the default theme directory root
register_theme_directory( get_theme_root() );
```

where

```
function get_theme_root( $stylesheet_or_template = false ) {
        global $wp_theme_directories;

        if ( $stylesheet_or_template && $theme_root = get_raw_theme_root( $stylesheet_or_template ) ) {
                // Always prepend WP_CONTENT_DIR unless the root currently registered as a theme directory.
                // This gives relative theme roots the benefit of the doubt when things go haywire.
                if ( ! in_array( $theme_root, (array) $wp_theme_directories ) )
                        $theme_root = WP_CONTENT_DIR . $theme_root;
        } else {
                $theme_root = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes';
        }

        return apply_filters( 'theme_root', $theme_root );
}
```

The functions `get_theme_root()` and `get_raw_theme_root()` seems to be used in other theme related functions.

I don't see any theme related pre-defined constants used here so I would think that you are stuck with a plugin ;-)

Maybe playing around with the global `$wp_theme_directories` might get you somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I was giving thoughts to setting the global, but... Yuck... :-D At any rate, thanks for confirming...