# register_theme_directory somehow "fails" when folder is outside of WP-Folder

Tags: plugins, theme-development, directory, wp-config

This is a simple skeleton for WordPress, that makes it possible to have just "themes" and "plugins" under version control:

https://github.com/sourcerer-mike/WordPress-GIT-Skeleton

When doing `register_theme_directory(__DIR__ . '/themes');` with a folder that is outside of WP, the theme is shown in the backend and can be activated.

But when viewing the front end the page stays blank.

I guess it's up to the folder being one level above and unreachable for the client. But the server can access it, so I think I've done something wrong.

Is there any solution to have themes outside of WP but still working? (otherwise `register_theme_directory` is kind of useless)

Or is there a better solution to have those two outside?
(I also need to take care of not so experienced developer here)

My folder structure is like this:

```
├── plugins
├── public (document root of apache)
│   ├── wp-admin
│   ├── wp-content
│   │   ├── plugins
│   │   └── themes
│   │       ├── twentyeleven
│   │       ├── twentyten
│   │       ├── twentythirteen
│   │       └── twentytwelve
│   │       └── twentyfourteen
│   └── wp-includes
├── themes
│   └── foo
└── uploads
```

As soon as I change to theme "foo" the frontend stays white and empty (no single output).

Comment: The `theme_root` (`_uri`) is necessary to make the stylesheet work. Have you [tried that too](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83103/73)?

Comment: Didn't touch this. I just added the folder structure above. The alias for the theme seems to be irrelevant because the output is just empty. What do you think it should be?

Comment: It should be a publicly accessible URL. The empty page is probably the result of a suppressed error. See  [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot speak to your specific white-screen issue, registered theme directories must be within the Apache document root, at minimum.

Many files in themes, such as CSS, JS, images, etc, are served directly by the webserver, not via calls to WordPress. So having a theme directory that is not directly accessible and serve-able by the webserver process clearly will not work.